# UWP Assign inherited Text value from DependencyProperty callback throws exception

Tags: c#, uwp, dependency-properties

I am working on a custom input control inherited from TextBox that will be used to enter in a Social Security Number.  The end goal is to use a mask and display bullet characters instead of the actual numbers while storing the actual value in a dependency property called ActualValue.

I'm attempting to set the TextBox.Text value to the actual value (later to be swapped out for formatted hidden characters) and I am receiving an exception at the kernel level (no symbols available if I set to managed and native debugging) if I have an event handler on the TextChanging event and bind the value.

- no TextChanging eventhandler - no exception
- do not set Text in callback - no exception
- use literal (e.g. 123456) in markup instead of binding - no exception

I have used this pattern before (even in UWP applications), but the only difference that I can see in this example is that it is in new project with both minimum and target versions set to the Anniversary Update version... I'm not sure if that has anything to do with it.

I am not looking for a solution to the end goal... just help with why it is throwing an exception, please.

here is the class:

```
public class SSNInputBox : TextBox
{
    private static readonly string SSNMask = "___-__-____";

    public SSNInputBox()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(TextBox);
        TextChanging += OnTextChanging;
    }

    #region Properties

    private void OnTextChanging(TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
    {

    }

    public string ActualValue
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ActualValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ActualValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ActualValue.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ActualValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ActualValue", typeof(string), typeof(SSNInputBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, onActualValueChanged));

    private static void onActualValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((SSNInputBox)d).OnActualValueChanged(e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnActualValueChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and here is the markup:

```
<local:SSNInputBox ActualValue="{Binding Path=CurrentApplicant.SSN, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**UPDATE**
If I move the SSN to the main viewmodel as opposed to being a property of an INotifyPropertyChanged object in the viewmodel, it also works.

INP class:

```
public class Applicant : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _ssn;
    public string SSN
    {
        get { return _ssn; }
        set { Set(ref _ssn, value); }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

ViewModel (methods are called from code behind of mainpage during development)

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Applicant _currentApplicant = new Applicant();
    public Applicant CurrentApplicant
    {
        get { return _currentApplicant; }
        set { Set(ref _currentApplicant, value); }
    }

    private string _ssn = "123-45-6789";
    public string SSN
    {
        get { return _ssn; }
        set { Set(ref _ssn, value); }
    }

    public void LoadApplicant()
    {
        CurrentApplicant.SSN = "123-45-6789";
    }

    public void ChangeSSN()
    {
        CurrentApplicant.SSN = SSN = "987-65-4321";
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wonder, would inheriting from a `PasswordBox` simply all this?

Comment: Thanks, Justin... I've considered that.  However, PasswordBox is sealed and you cannot inherit from it.